# How can I invoke a method on a service that is hosted in Azure using Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a service that is hosted in Azure. There is a method in the service that returns an integer. Is there a way I can invoke that method using Powershell?

Comment: Is it a Web service? Does it have authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using the Invoke-WebReqest outlined in MSDN.